# How to redirect form App.js file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

After successful login I want to redirect to `"/dashboard"`. I cannot use `useNavigate()` hook as it is in App.js file and it is not inside `<Router>` component.

Below is my code.

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './Login';
import Signup from './Signup';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, redirect, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  // const navigate = useNavigate();

  const hanldeEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  }

  const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const resp = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
        email,
        password
      });
      if (resp.status === 200) {
        console.log(resp)
        const { token, refreshToken } = resp.data;
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refreshToken);
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        // return navigate('/dashboard');
        redirect('/dashboard')
        // <Navigate to='/dashboard' replace />
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <Signup />
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      element: <Login handlePasswordChange={handlePasswordChange} hanldeEmailChange={hanldeEmailChange} hanldeSubmit={handleLogin} />
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      element: '<div>Dashboard</div>'
    }
  ])
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried `redirect` and `Navigate` from `react-router-dom` but it is not working either.

Answer (score 1):

If `App` is rendered *outside* the router (*because its rendering the router itself*) then you could use a `window.location.href` redirect the browser, but this will also reload the page and likely lose the `isAuthenticated` state in `App` when the entire app remounts.

Refactor the code such `App` is rendered within the router so it can access the routing context and use the `useNavigate` hook and all the other React-Router components and hooks.

Example:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const AppLayout = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const navigate = useNavigate(); // <-- use hook

  const hanldeEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const resp = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
        email,
        password
      });
      if (resp.status === 200) {
        console.log(resp)
        const { token, refreshToken } = resp.data;
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refreshToken);
        setIsAuthenticated(true);

        navigate('/dashboard'); // <-- navigate now
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Outlet // <-- return outlet for nested routes
      context={{ // <-- pass handlers down in Outlet's context provider
        isAuthenticated,
        handleEmailChange,
        handlePasswordChange,
        handleLogin,
      }}
    />;
  );
};

export default AppLayout;
```

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
  const {
    handleEmailChange,
    handlePasswordChange,
    handleLogin,
  } = useOutletContext(); // <-- access handlers from outlet context

  ...
};
```

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppLayout from './path/to/AppLayout';
import Login from './Login';
import Signup from './Signup';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />, // <-- renders Outlet for nested routes
    children: [
      // <-- all these routes render content into parent Outlet
      { path: '/', element: <Signup /> },
      { path: '/login', element: <Login /> },
      { path: '/dashboard', element: <div>Dashboard</div> },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

Since the `email` and `password` values are ephemeral, i.e. they don't need to exist for the life of the app, I suggest also moving all the `email` and `password` state and login handlers into your `Login` component, passing down just the `isAuthenticated` state and a handler to set/update it.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to try this way

```
    import { useState } from 'react'
import {Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false)
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        setLogin(true)
    }


  return (
    <>

        { login && (
                  <Navigate to="/test" replace={true} />

        )} 
            Welcome
            <div>Welcome</div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>
                Click
            </button>

    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

its the way in the docs for react route
[reactRouteNavigation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate)